# haml を用いたビューの一部を再利用できるように、 block を渡すようなヘルパーが作れないか

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

内容としましては、「Rails 4.0 環境において、 haml を用いた view のある部分を helper 化したいのですが、うまくいかない」です。

```
%li{class: "#{current_page?(:root) ? : 'active' : ''}"}
  = link_to :root do
    = fa_icon 'home'
    ホーム
%li{class: "#{current_page?(:blogs) ? : 'active' : ''}"}
  = link_to :blogs do
    = fa_icon 'book'
    記事
```

`li` タグでリストしつつ、その配下にある `a` タグの path が `current_page` と同じだった場合は、 `active` という `class` を `li` タグへ与えるのですが、この `li` タグ部分を全てヘルパーで表現したいです。

- ヘルパーには、 path と block を与えたい（もしくは、font-awesome 用の引数と `a` タグの `title` 部分も）
- つまり、以下のどちらかのようなイメージで使用したい

  ```
  = li_helper(:root) do
    = link_to :root do
      = fa_icon 'home'
      ホーム
  ```

  または

  ```
  = li_helper(:root, 'home', 'ホーム')
  ```

いずれも出力イメージは、 root ページで出力したとして、

```
%li.active
  = link_to :root do
    = fa_icon 'home'
    ホーム
```

となって欲しいです。

どのように helper を定義したら実現できるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

僕が実装するなら、`link_with_icon`と、`active_class`のような2つのヘルパーを作ると思います。

```haml
%li{class: active_class(:root)}
  = link_with_icon 'ホーム', :root, icon: 'home'
```

```rb
module FooHelper
  def active_class(options)
    current_page?(options) ? 'active' : nil
  end

  def link_with_icon(name, path, icon:)
    link_to path do
      fa_icon icon, text: name
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: メソッドの引数部分の、icon:の部分は、iconかと思いますが、1文字の修正のためか編集できませんでしたのでここに書いておきます。

Comment: デフォルト値なしのキーワード引数を意図して`icon:`と書きました。参考: http://techracho.bpsinc.jp/baba/2013_12_26/15026

Comment: 上記文法、恥ずかしながら知らずでした。失礼しました。
ただ、先ほど実装して試したところ、`missing keyword: icon`として、ArgumentErrorが返ってきてしまいました。
`= link_with_icon('ホーム', :admin_root, 'home')`とした場合です。
ヘルパーメソッド内のコロンを排した場合、期待通りにworkします。。
（Ruby 2.1.2環境です）

Comment: `= link_with_icon('ホーム', :admin_root, icon: 'home')` とすると、動くと思います。

Answer (score 3):

表題に沿って、ブロック渡す方法を紹介します。

ヘルパでこんな感じにして

```
def li_helper(path, name, &block)
  content_tag :li,
              link_to(path){ block.call() },
              class: ('home' == name ? 'active' : '')
end
```

ビューでこう呼び出します。

```
= li_helper(:root, 'home') do
  ホーム
```

`block.call()` ではなく `yield` を使えば暗黙的パラメータも使えますし、 `block_given?` を使えば、渡された時とそうでないときの分岐もできます( `link_to` の内部実装がそんな感じですね)

`content_tag` を `haml_tag` に置き換えることもできます。この場合呼び出し側が `=` でなく `-` になるようです。